# Installing MacOS 11.3 creates a Relocated Items.nosync with changes to private/etc/group

Tags: security, install, big-sur

I just installed MacOS 11.3. I now have a folder on my desktop called Relocated Items.nosync. It contains a file called group.system_default inside Configuration/private/etc which the docs says is the default Apple would normally have installed but it left my modified file in place.

I compared the two files. The difference is that the system default file Apple would have installed includes one additional line: _trustd:*:282:_trustd

I have read that this process relates to security certificates and so this causes me a little concern.

Does anyone have any insight what the best course of action is? Install Apple's recommended file including the trustd line? Or leave my modified file without that line in place? Do something else?

Related thread on MacRumors:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/newly-assigned-objects-nosync-folder-on-desktop-after-updating-to-11-3.2293368/

Comment: Thanks, that later posted question appears to be a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

After few months realized there is an extra item on desktop which I didn't create (called *Relocated Items*) so I guess machine was running even when this was not merged into /etc/group anymore. So I deleted it.

The only thing came up on my Filemerge was:

LHS: **/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Configuration/private/etc/group**

RHS: **/etc/group**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I open this folder, I delete its contents, then I delete the alias on the Desktop. :)

Comment: I note 11.3 didn't kick me out of `sudoers` which all 11.x versions have done so far. Ah well, I guess I got enough practise using `su admin` and `visudo`