# Relocated items after macOS update to 11.3.1

Tags: macos, big-sur

After updating my macOS to 11.3.1 from 11.3, a directory named `Relocated Items` appeared on my desktop.
A document in that directory explained a bit about what's going on. I will attach the text of the document below.

so I viewed a diff between `/etc/group` and `~/Desktop/.../group.system_default` and saw that
the line containing `_trustd:*:282:_trustd` exists in `group.system_default` but not in `/etc/group`.
Another odd thing I realized is the 'Date modified' on the file on `group.system_default` is 1. Jan 2020. This computer and the install are both from 2021.

Can somebody explain what is going on? I am not sure which of the files came with the macos-update and which I suposedly modified in the previous version.
I also don't understand what `_trustd:*:282:_trustd` means.

**Document in Relocated Items Directory**

> During the last macOS upgrade or file migration, some of your files couldn’t be moved to their
> new locations. This folder contains these files.
>
> **Configuration files**
> These configuration files were modified or customised by you, by another user or by an app.
> The modifications may be incompatible with the recent macOS upgrade. The modified files are
> in the Configuration folder, organised in subfolders named after their original locations.
>
> To restore any of the custom configurations, compare your modifications with the configuration
> changes made during the macOS upgrade and combine them when possible.
>
> Configuration files with the suffix "system_default" were edited or customised but the changes
> were allowed to remain installed. The system_default version of the file is provided to
> demonstrate what the Apple-supplied version of this file would look like.
> It is recommended you compare the two and evaluate whether you wish to integrate any changes
> Apple may have made to the default version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing MacOS 11.3 creates a Relocated Items.nosync with changes to private/etc/group](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419519/installing-macos-11-3-creates-a-relocated-items-nosync-with-changes-to-private-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question, which file is the modified one, the document you've added already explains that:

> Configuration files with the suffix "system_default" were edited or
> customised but the changes were allowed to remain installed

...which means your current file "group" is the modified one and "group.system_default" is the default one, but wasn't installed, because the changes to "group" were allowed.

> _trustd:*:282:_trustd

...is a user of the same named group on your computer, as also found in "Directory Utility.app" (for which you can search in Spotlight).
"282" is the "PrimaryGroupID".

The man pages for `trustd` mention:

```
trustd(8)                 BSD System Manager's Manual                trustd(8)

NAME
     trustd -- Daemon and LaunchAgent that performs trust evaluations

SYNOPSIS
     trustd

DESCRIPTION
     trustd provides services for evaluating trust in certificates for all processes on the system.

     This command is not intended to be invoked directly.

BSD                               May 7, 2021                              BSD
```

Who initiated the changes, or why, I cannot say - I would think you yourself should have a better idea, if you've done any modifications, or which application you've installed, that could have changed the "group" file.
Or maybe somebody else here knows.

About the date: if you look through the system volume, you may find that pretty much all system files have the same modification date (which is new in Big Sur with its boot snapshot).

Comment: Can you think of a reason why any app or user config would remove trustd? Reading the description you posted, it sounds like a bad thing.

Comment: @Human No, but Google finds an already existing thread on MacRumors, with quite a few people noticing the same.  The consensus seems to be the same, as in benwiggy's answer (which, for some reason was downvoted, after I'd voted it up).  After all, _trustd should still exist (if you check in "Directory Utility"), but read for yourself: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/newly-assigned-objects-nosync-folder-on-desktop-after-updating-to-11-3.2293368/

Comment: @Human Looking through 6 of my "Previously Relocated Items" folders also eventually finds the group file.  So it seems to be Apple's doing...

Comment: Yeah thanks for the link. I will put the line containing trustd back in the groupfile.

Answer (score 2):

My policy is that it falls into the category of "Nothing to worry about" and I delete them every time with no noticeable side-effects. (At worst, the system_defaults files will be restored to Relocated Items on the next system update.)

But Apple does seem to be saying "You have some system files which are different from their defaults, so instead of restoring the defaults, we're going to leave them here, and let you decide which one you should install."
... which is a very un-Apple thing to do.

Comment: How did you decide it belongs to the "Nothing to worry about" ? Something like this makes me very curious and I hope to learn from it.

Comment: Because it's unlike Apple to let its users make crucial decisions about Unix config files and other such files.

Comment: FYI to anyone: After reading all the stuff, I decided to not do anything except delete the thing from my Desktop.  If something weird starts to happen, I still have the files under /Users/Shared but I doubt I'm going to need them.